# How to return an object instead of an array? (mysql with node,js)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

Hey so quick and short I just started using mysql today and I grasped creating a table, inserting rows in that table, querying rows, updating and deleting etc.. But I cant figure out how to return an object if im returning a single object.

for example:

I want to return an object like this

{title: 'object1', body: 'this is object number 1'}

instead it returns

[{ title: 'object1', body: 'this is object number 1 }]

I am usedto using mongodb with mongoose and when I used

collection.findOne I got an object if I used collection.find I got an array

So must I always return an array instead of object with mysql? I have heard of WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER I tried using it like this

```
 let query = `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=1, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER`;

 connection.query(query, (err, results, feilds) => {
     if(err) throw err;
     //etc...
 });
```

But I get a syntax error stating "ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER' at line 1"

If anyone can help shine some light on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the returned response will always be a single object, then it's easy to return the first index of the array. Instead of `return response`, we can do `return response[0]`, right??

Comment: Yes true I am just wondering if there is a way to return a plain object. if there is not that works for me

Comment: Both MySQL and MSSQL use SQL but with a slight variation in the syntax. Perhaps, you're trying to use `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` in MySQL, which is actually a syntax in MSSQL. Unlike mongoDB, in MySQL, we do not have functions like `find()` and `findOne()` that return object and array respectively. We only have `SELECT`, which alone can return both single or multiple objects, hence returns an array by default.

Comment: Yep that was my problem I was getting the two mixed up thinking they are the same. Thanks your comment really cleared things up